# chatgpt-shell, could not find package

Tags: use-package

I'm trying to install chatgpt-shell, so I eval:

```
(use-package chatgpt-shell
  :ensure t
  :custom
  ((chatgpt-shell-openai-key
    (lambda ()
      (auth-source-pass-get 'secret "openai-key")))))
```

..and I get this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not find package chatgpt-shell. Updating rec...")
  signal(error ("Could not find package chatgpt-shell. Updating rec..."))
  error("Could not find package %S. Updating recipe reposit..." chatgpt-shell (org-elpa melpa gnu-elpa-mirror nongnu-elpa el-get emacsmirror-mirror))
  straight--convert-recipe(chatgpt-shell nil)
  straight-use-package(chatgpt-shell)
  (progn (straight-use-package 'chatgpt-shell) (defvar use-package--warning116 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*use-package*") (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "-----\n" msg "\n\n(use-package chatgpt-shell :ensure t :custom\n  (...") (emacs-lisp-mode)) (setq msg (concat msg " (see the *use-package* buffer)")) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case-unless-debug err (progn (let ((custom--inhibit-theme-enable nil)) (unless (memq 'use-package custom-known-themes) (deftheme use-package) (enable-theme 'use-package) (setq custom-enabled-themes (remq 'use-package custom-enabled-themes))) (custom-theme-set-variables 'use-package '(chatgpt-shell-openai-key (lambda nil ...) nil nil "Customized with use-package chatgpt-shell"))) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package chatgpt-shell") (prog1 (if (not (require ... nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" ...) :error)) (let ((elapsed ...)) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package chatgpt-shell" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package chatgpt-shell")))))) (error (funcall use-package--warning116 :catch err))))
  (use-package chatgpt-shell :ensure t :custom ((chatgpt-shell-openai-key (lambda nil (auth-source-pass-get 'secret "openai-key")))))
  (progn (use-package chatgpt-shell :ensure t :custom ((chatgpt-shell-openai-key (lambda nil (auth-source-pass-get 'secret "openai-key"))))) (setq chatgpt-shell-openai-key "sk-6SXUtk..."))
  eval((progn (use-package chatgpt-shell :ensure t :custom ((chatgpt-shell-openai-key (lambda nil (auth-source-pass-get 'secret "openai-key"))))) (setq chatgpt-shell-openai-key "sk-AmerXS2ePDpVtk...")) nil)
  org-babel-execute:elisp("(use-package chatgpt-shell\n  :ensure t\n  :custom\n ..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:session . "none") (:cache . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:lexical . "no") (:tangle . "yes")))
  org-babel-execute-src-block(nil ("elisp" "(use-package chatgpt-shell\n  :ensure t\n  :custom\n ..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace") (:exports . "code") (:tangle . "yes") (:lexical . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" nil 330028 "(ref:%s)"))
  org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
  call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
  command-execute(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

I reported this to chatgpt-shell and he tells me to:

```
package-refresh-contents
```

, but this does not help;)

Here's my use-package config:

```
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(setq straight-repository-branch "develop") ; Need this for new org-contrib location
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
    (url-retrieve-synchronously
     "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
     'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
(straight-use-package 'use-package)

; By default, use-package uses package.el to install packages. To use straight.el instead of package.el, pass the :straight option: 
(use-package evil-commentary
  :straight t)
```

Any pointers as to how I can troubleshoot this?;)

EDIT:
My package-archives is:

```
package-archives is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.

Its value is
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
 ("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/"))
```

I see there's no melpa there, but I think that was removed when I installed quelpa:

```
(require 'use-package)
;; NOW QEULPA
(use-package quelpa
  :init
  (setq quelpa-self-upgrade-p nil))
(use-package quelpa-use-package
  :after (quelpa)
  :config
  (quelpa-use-package-activate-advice))
```

Comment: Add the value of `package-archives` to your question.

Comment: AFAICT, `chatgpt-shell` is only in `MELPA`. See https://melpa.org/#/quelpa

Comment: "I see there's no melpa there, but I think that was removed when I installed quelpa" - I doubt that installing `quelpa` removed `melpa`: the two are different things. Please add `melpa` back and try again.